# Poor performance of reads in pthreads hash table using read-write locks

Tags: c, linux, locking, pthreads, hashtable

I've put together a simple key value store which speaks a subset of the [Redis](http://redis.io/) protocol. It uses pthreads on Linux to share the hash table; I use pthreads rwlocks to manage access to this table. I've been testing the K-V store using the Redis benchmark tool.

With a single client, I can do about 2500 SET operations a second. However, it can only do about 25 GETs per second; I'd expect the other way around, so this surprises me. It scales to some extent, so if I throw 10 clients at it I'll get nearly 9000 SETs per second and around 250 GETs per second.

My GET code is pretty simple; I lock the table, find the appropriate hash table location, and check for a matching key in the linked-list there. For a GET, I use `pthread_rwlock_rdlock` and `pthread_rwlock_unlock` when I'm done. For SET, I use `pthread_rwlock_wrlock` and `pthread_rwlock_unlock`. SET is quite a bit more complex than GET.

I also made the code work on Plan 9, using shared-memory processes and their own implementation of read/write locks. There, GETs are almost as fast as SETs, instead of 100x slower. This makes me think my hash table code is probably ok; I use exactly the same hash table code for both OSes, I simply use #defines to select the appropriate lock for each OS (the interface is the same in both cases, lucky!).

I'm not very experienced with pthreads. Can anyone help me figure out why my performance is sucking so badly?

(Note: this isn't meant to be a high-performing K-V store, it's meant to be a naively written test application/benchmark. It handles requests in about the simplest method possible, by spinning off a new thread for every client)

Comment: Are you setting `TCP_NODELAY` on the socket?

Comment: Could you show the relevant bits of the code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know rwlocks but the experience I made with conditional locks with pthreads was, that with a realtime kernel the conditions were woken up faster. You can even tune the programs priority with `chrt`command.